Authentication failed in postman for listing the tables in azure storage account
I'm trying to list the table names present in the azure storage account that is enabled with public access using the postman but i'm getting the authentication failed error:
Error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code>AuthenticationFailed</code>
    <message xml:lang="en-US">Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId: alphanumeric id
Time:2024-04-23T12:32:52.6326261Z</message>
</error>

URL: https://srcstoreacc131.table.core.windows.net/Tables?SASToken
Method: GET



How are you creating the SAS token? Please edit your question and include that. – Gaurav Mantri

In the Storage Account > SAS Menu > Selecting Table and permissions as list and then generating the SAS URL/tokens.

Make sure to include SAS token with sig correctly. You will get that error even if there is space at the end of sig while running API https://i.imgur.com/KUK4jm1.png.

Try allowing Container as one of the resource types when constructing the SAS.

How are you creating the SAS token? Please edit your question and include that.

The error occurs if you are not passing valid SAS token while calling the API. Initially, I too got same error when I ran the API with extra space after sig like this:
GET https://storageaccname.table.core.windows.net/Tables?SASToken

Response:

To resolve the error, generate the SAS token with correct permissions and include it properly with valid signature while calling API.
In my case, I generated SAS token by selecting below permissions:


When I called the REST API again with valid SAS token by removing extra space at the end, I got the response successfully with list of tables like this:
GET https://storageaccname.table.core.windows.net/Tables?SASToken

Response:

